# User Location-Mapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I would like to find out userlocation coordinate while my app is loading. I have implemented following code but it returns 0.000

```
 mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;

CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinate;
annotationCoordinate.latitude=mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
NSLog(@"%f",annotationCoordinate.latitude);
```

I could not able to figure out. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should take into account that it takes time to retrieve the user location. Moreover the user can disable the location service for your application or even the location service can be unavailable during the connectivity conditions. So you'd better to rethink your application starting procedures.

When you make up you decision take a look at `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` method of `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol. After this method fires out the location can be available via the `userLocation` property of the `MKMapView`.

*UPDATE*

In case you want to open map view with the user location already checked, you may consider using `CLLocationManager` and `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. This way you can check if the location service is available and open map view after the method `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` fires up.

For the complete info take a look at [Getting the User’s Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1) programing guide

Comment: My idea is to place annotation to user location initially. That is why I should have to find user location coordinate. Your suggestion is to implement MKMapViewDelegate, however, it would recall continously. That is what I dont want . any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving detail answer. My question is now, I am using CLLocationManager and Delegate. How could I stop my code be assure that I got my lat and long then resume back to work.

Comment: You just can create MKMapView instance and add it to your view controller in `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get users location coordinate in view did load what you need to do is using the delegate method below.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSLog(@"coordinates = %f,%f", mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,
          mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Make sure your map object is connected with the delegate
Just tested it should work

Comment: But I would like to show user location while my app loading! How this delegate would be called ?

Comment: if you connect the delegate and copy and paste the code that I gave you when the application launched this delegate method will get called immediately. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Heres' the explanation from app doc "While the showsUserLocation property is set to YES, this method is called whenever a new location update is received by the map view. This method is also called if the map view’s user tracking mode is set to MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading and the heading changes.

This method is not called if the application is currently running in the background. If you want to receive location updates while running in the background, you must use the Core Location framework."

Comment: I dont want to keep track of user location continously. I just want to get user location lat and long initially only.

Comment: So simply cancel the location retrieval once you get an accurate enough value.  `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`

Answer (score 1):

**1) Add the FrameWork CoreLocation and Mapkit**
**2) In ViewController.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
      CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

**3) In viewController.m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.mapView.delegate = self;
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 locationManager.delegate=self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

**now in didUpdateUserLocation**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
// Add an annotation
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
point.title = @"Where am I?";
point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];}
```

**4) Now add Mapview in your UI**

**NOTE**: select **MapView** and goto **Attribute Inspector** and **CKECK Mark the Shows user location** Under BEHAVIOUR

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Then in viewDidLoad method:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationManager.location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2))];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    NSLog(@"%f",mapView.region.center.latitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just managed to fix it myself too. What no one is telling you is that you need to set a key/value pair in the info.plist.

Depending on what method (requestAlwaysAuthorization or requestWhenInUseAuthorization) you need to add a key under the 'Information Property List' dictionary. For the first method use: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and for the second method use: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription .

The value fields of both keys can be set to whatever string you would like to display to the user.

Both keys at the top are what we are looking for.
[image: How it should look like]

Now you should see a dialogue that prompts you for confirmation.

PS: No tutorial on the internet listed this step of the process, but when you read the documentation for each of those methods (requestWhenInUse on CLLocationManager) it does mention that nothing gets displayed without those two keys.